# How do I get the name of the WPF Datagrid ItemsSource Table

Tags: wpf

My datagrid is used to display data from 2 tables, (independently) based on user selection of the data required. How Do I get the name of the table that is currently being used as the ItemsSource for the grid?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? Can we see a bit of your XAML and ViewModel ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid has been set or bound to a DataView of a DataTable you could cast it back to a DataView and get the name of the table from the TableName property of the DataView's Table property like this:

```
DataView dv = dg.ItemsSource as DataView;
if(dv != null && dv.Table != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dv.Table.TableName);
}
```

Full sample:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable() { TableName = "t1" };
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        dt.Rows.Add("Donald Duck");
        dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dg.ItemsSource as DataView;
        if (dv != null && dv.Table != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dv.Table.TableName);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" />
<Button Content="Get" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Comment: That was what I needed, I could see it in the IntelliSense but just didn't know how to cast it, I tried several things and I was close, but didn't get there your code works perfectly Greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a DataTable from the ItemsSource instead.

```
DataTable dv = dg.ItemsSource as DataTable;
if(dv != null && dv.Table != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dv.Table.TableName);
}
```